# From MDT to Deployment to new machies

Tags: windows-server-2012, mdt

I recently took a crash course on using MDT and deployment for an organisation. From my understanding this is the ideal way to handle deployment.

With MDT you create a base image that you deploy to a Hyper-V Machine. In this image you configure the Features and install packages such as SilverLight, VC++ ReDists, network settings, other system settings, and others packages that do not require constant updates or likely to change.

From there you install the drivers in/on the Hyper-V machine and then you sysprep that Hyper-v Machine and use that .ISO/.WIM image and push it to WDS and then network boot and install that image.

Is this the ideal way or does it really depend mostly on the situation or amount/type of machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDT is a great tool for deployments, and is very flexible… For example, the base image that you are creating can be a basic Windows install with all updates in it (thin image), or you can install software that everyone needs to this base image (thick image), then run the Sysprep and Capture task. The TechNet Magazine article ‘[Desktop Image Management: Build a Better Desktop Image](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff721826.aspx)’ will help you decide on the best process for your specific needs.
Additionally, you can have MDT install software using the ‘Applications’ section of MDT, instead of the ‘Packages’ section (Node), using command lines and pointing MDT to the location of the install files.

Drivers should not be added to the virtual machine, but to the ‘Out of Box Drivers’ section in MDT. MDT uses Plug and Play hardware calls to choose the correct driver from this section during the deployment. This allows you to have drives for all the models of computers that your company uses in MDT, instead of in the image.

To further explain some of these details, please see the following videos:

[Deployment Day Session 1: Introduction to MDT 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/tdbe12-deployment-day-session1.aspx)

[Deployment Day Session 2: MDT 2012 Advanced](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/tdbe12-deployment-day-session2)

[Windows 8.1 Deployment Jumpstart](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/windows-8-1-deployment-jump-start)

More videos and articles to help with MDT can be found on the [Deploy Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/dd641427.aspx) and [Deploy Windows 8.1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh974336) pages of the Springboard Series on TechNet.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the ideal way or does it really depend mostly on the situation
> or amount/type of machines?

Ideal is relative to what type of environment you have.  That being said, the way you described is a viable, efficient method if you do it right.  Here is my opinion on MDT vs WDS as you've referenced them both.

MDT is better suited for larger enterprises and WDS is better suited for smaller businesses.  I've used both methods (MDT & WDS), and they both serve a great purpose.  WDS does work in tandem with MDT as you mentioned in your question too as it helps with the network/PXE boot portion of MDT.

The scenario you described in your question would be more geared towards the smaller environment I mentioned earlier in that you created your image and installed apps and drivers then sysprep'd it and took that image to use to blast down to your computers through WDS.  MDT takes this portion and makes it much easier, and much more efficient through the task sequences it uses.  You spend a lot of time upfront (way more than WDS) setting up all of your models and their driver packages (CABs from the vendors' (Dell, HP, etc.) websites), network settings, naming conventions, etc., etc., but in the end there is a lot less fussing with it and it is very scalable once you've got it to your liking.  WDS uses set images as you already know and can put driver packages in these images, but there is a lot of tweaking when you get new models of computers that you have to do to keep WDS running.  With MDT you edit the task sequence that you've already created and throw a new item in with the new driver CAB once a new model of computer comes out and it's quite a bit easier; having done all the hard work up front of course.

MDT also excels in the area of targeting.  What I mean by this, is that you can have a thin image with no drivers or any applications installed, launch an MDT deployment that runs a task sequence that you've setup to detect which type of computer you're running, find which model it is, then get specific driver packs and application packages and install them.  All this is accomplished using WMI queries that query certain attributes of the computers you'll be imaging.  This really helps in shops/companies where there isn't a standard model of computer.

[Here is a great guide for setting up MDT](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813172714/http://geekswithblogs.net/Wchrabaszcz/archive/2013/11/12/sccm2012-r2--how-to-integrate-mdt-with-sccm.aspx), and [here is a great link to video tutorials and guides for actually USING it](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA25F5E710C52D8AC&src_vid=HHDrfMTOIp4&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_1008227531).  Please feel free to contact me regarding any other specific questions you might have.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the ideal way or does it really depend mostly on the situation
>   or amount/type of machines?

It all depends...

- **WDS** has a steep learning curve and you need an MS Server platform.
- **MDT** and **SCCM** have both a steeper learning curve and they rely on WDS.
- **WDS**, **MDT**, and **SCCM** present limitations when deploying non-Windows assets

If your environment does not force you to take a particular solution and you need quick results there are third parties automated PXE servers Solution Accelerators able to make life easier when network deploying both Windows and non-Windows assets.

Comment: WDS doesn't have a steep learning curve; especially if you've used any sort of imaging software before.

Comment: I disagree; WDS does have a steep learning curve.